# Displaying an icon in a picturebox

Tags: c#, icons, picturebox

I am trying to display `icon file` in a picture box. I'm using this code to set the image.

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Icon(openFileDialog.FileName, new Size(48, 48)).ToBitmap();
```

But I'm getting this exception.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Requested range extends past the end of the array.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CopyToNative(Object source, Int32 startIndex, IntPtr destination, Int32 length)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(Byte[] source, Int32 startIndex, IntPtr destination, Int32 length)
   at System.Drawing.Icon.ToBitmap()
```

How to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved the problem.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromHicon(new Icon(openFileDialog.FileName, new Size(48, 48)).Handle);
```

Answer (score 4):

Some icons are sized incorrectly 48x48 to 32x32.

My final code is:

```
    Bitmap _image;
    try
    {
     _image = new Icon(icon, width, height).ToBitmap();
    }
    catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
     _image = Bitmap.FromHicon(new Icon(icon, new Size(width, height)).Handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `Bitmap.FromHicon` doesn't convert perfectly. I find another solution:

```
// event Paint of pictureBox1
void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(theIcon, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 for native event methods, and works out of the box. Use with `Icon myIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@filePath);`