# Error showing Icon in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, picturebox

I've been using this code to show an icon in a picturebox.

```
Image FromIcon(Icon ico)
{
    try
    {
        this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, "The icon of the Executable");
        return ico.ToBitmap();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, "Don't worry, it looks perfectly fine on the executable!");
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace);
        Clipboard.SetText(e.Message + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace);

        // Alternate method             
        return Bitmap.FromHicon(ico.Handle);
    }
}
```

However it is showing this error.

```
Requested range extends past the end of the array.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CopyToNative(Object source, Int32 startIndex, IntPtr destination, Int32 length)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(Byte[] source, Int32 startIndex, IntPtr destination, Int32 length)
   at System.Drawing.Icon.ToBitmap()
```

Also the icon is shown in a nasty way,

[image]

That's the same icon I use for my application. What can go wrong?

That icon is 32 bit as well as the other.

[image]

If I use another icon, it works fine and no error pops up.

[image]

Comment: How many bits is the image? not sure if >32 Bit is supported (if its possible?)

Comment: @Sayse I don't know how to say the bits of image. I'll upload the icon if you want.

Comment: I think it might be needed, otherwise, try using any other icon and seeing if that works fine

Comment: use  Bitmap.FromHicon  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782857/displaying-an-icon-in-a-picturebox

Comment: @MrFox That's the alternate method I'm using but it's not rendering fine.

Comment: What's 'fine'? Can you explain this in your question and include an example of what the icon should look like?

Comment: It's working for icon. How can I solve that?

Comment: Always avoid Bitmap.FromHicon(), it generates an icon that's guaranteed to work on ancient Windows versions.  Back when "ugly" still meant "normal".  Use an icon editor that can do a better job and use the .ico it generates.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using an icon editor to save the .ico file. That `Bitmap.FromHicon()` part is to show the icon in an abnormal way when it is not possible to show directly.

Comment: @MrFox I've included an image of what it looked like in the editor.

Comment: @Sayse I've included the image. It's 32 bit.

Comment: I suppose its possible that your image is really 31 x 31 but your ico generator believes it is 32 x 32, are you able to try using a different generator?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I recently came across the same issue so thought I would post the resolution for anyone else facing the same problem.

For me, the issue was that I was creating the ICO files from PNG image formats but the application that the files were used in targeted a .NET framework that was earlier than 4.6 (i.e. the version in which support was added for PNG frames in .ico files). See note from the Icon.ToBitmap() documentation below:

> Beginning with framework version 4.6 support was added for PNG frames in .ico files. Applications that target earlier versions of the framework but are running on the 4.6 bits can opt in into the new behavior by adding the following line to the <runtime> section of the app.config file:<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Drawing.DontSupportPngFramesInIcons=false" />

So once I added the above line to the app.config file it resolved the issue.