# Convert Icon to Png

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, gdi+

I am using the following code (based on something I found in another answer) to convert an image (usually it's a PNG added to project resources) to an Icon for use in form titles and such.

```
public static Icon IconFromImage(Image img)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(img))
    {
        Byte[] ba;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ba = ms.ToArray();
        }

        using (var imgData = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(imgData))
        {
            if (writer != null)
            {
                //Header (6 bytes)
                writer.Write((Byte)0);              // 0 reserved: set to 0
                writer.Write((Byte)0);              // 1 reserved: set to 0
                writer.Write((Int16)1);             // 2-3 image type: 1 = icon, 2 = cursor
                writer.Write((Int16)1);             // 4-5 number of images

                //Image entry #1 (16 bytes)
                writer.Write((Byte)bmp.Width);      // 0 image width
                writer.Write((Byte)bmp.Height);     // 1 image height
                writer.Write((Byte)0);              // 2 number of colors
                writer.Write((Byte)0);              // 3 reserved
                writer.Write((Int16)0);             // 4-5 color planes
                writer.Write((Int16)32);            // 6-7 bits per pixel
                writer.Write(ba.Length);            // 8-11 size of image data
                writer.Write(6 + 16);               // 12-15 offset to image data

                //Write image data
                writer.Write(ba);                   // PNG data must contain the whole PNG data file!

                writer.Flush();
                writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                return new Icon(imgData,16,16);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

From image to Icon works fine.  But there is one instance where I need to grab that form's title Icon and get an Image back from that.  This used to work when I was using actual file-based ICO files for the title images, but now that I'm using the conversion code to get the Icon for the form, the resulting PNGs look horrible.

Form's title Icon:

[image]

Image rendered using `Bitmap.FromHicon(new Icon(theForm.Icon, new Size(16, 16)).Handle)`:
(Note: used to use `theForm.Icon.ToBitmap()`, but that now errors)

[image]

I read a comment on another post where a user stated that if PNG is used to derive the Icon, then coming back to image would be bad "because PNGs have more than one bit of transparency".  If that is the problem I am experiencing, then what can I do about it?

Comment: What's the problem with `var img = this.Icon.ToBitmap()`?

Comment: There is no high quality encoder for icons. [Extract icon from file then save as .ico file with transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37354129/1070452)  might answer your question

Comment: @RezaAghaei That generic version doesn't seem to like the 32bpp specification.  If I either change `writer.Write((Int16)32)` to be 24bpp, or use the one that demands 16x16 size, it's good.  I get an array overrun exception.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I used this [icon](http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i43427/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/Status-security-medium.ico) as `Icon` of my `Form`. Then used `this.pictureBox1.Image = this.Icon.ToBitmap();`. The quality is completely acceptable. Did I miss something in question?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, I think you did.  This has nothing to do with `ToBitmap()`.  It has everything to do with taking a PNG file, putting it through the code I provided, and then trying to get that in-memory ICO back to a PNG without the quality suffering.

Comment: OK, I got it. In fact you want to convert a png to icon and back it to png without loosing quality and alpha.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IconBitmapDecoder` to get icon stream preserving pixel format and the using `PngBitmapEncoder`save that stream in a png image:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
class IconHelper
{
    public static Bitmap PngFromIcon(Icon icon)
    {
        Bitmap png = null;
        using (var iconStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            icon.Save(iconStream);
            var decoder = new IconBitmapDecoder(iconStream,
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                BitmapCacheOption.None);

            using (var pngSteam = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(decoder.Frames[0]);
                encoder.Save(pngSteam);
                png = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(pngSteam);
            }
        }
        return png;
    }
}
```

To use those classes you need to add a reference to `PresentationCore`, `WindowsBase` and `System.Xaml`. Then the usage would be:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = IconHelper.PngFromIcon(this.Icon);
```

And the result is the same as the original png which you used to create the icon.

Comment: That works beautifully, Reza.  Thank you very much.  I did not have to include `System.Xaml`, by the way.

Comment: I was checking it on .NET 4.0, I'll check it using .NET 4.5. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: In .NET 4.8 it is `System.Drawing`, not `System.Xaml` that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try Bitmap.FromHicon(this.Icon.Handle), you may get better results.  At the least ToBitmap() seems to barf if the png has compression: [Displaying an icon in a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782857/displaying-an-icon-in-a-picturebox), http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/21851.aspx

Comment: I think that's essentially equivalent to `theForm.Icon.ToBitmap()`, which, when I can get it to work by lowering encoding quality to 24bpp, does not present a better result.

Comment: In that case I'd just suggest sticking a field on your form to take carry the original bitmap around so you can take it from there :)

Comment: I'm hoping it doesn't come to that.  Shouldn't, since this worked before when I was using "professional" icons.