# Print An Image On Page With C#

Tags: c#, image, printing

I have a 256x256 .ico that I want to print through my C# syntax.  This is my syntax

```
Image logoImage = global::Winform1.Properties.Resources.KA0_icon.ToBitmap();
Rectangle LogoRect = new Rectangle(m_leftMargin, m_leftMargin, (int)(logoImage.Width * 0.75), (int)(logoImage.Height * 0.8));
e.Graphics.DrawImage(logoImage, LogoRect);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, LogoRect);
```

But this throws an error of:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Requested range extends past the end of the array

What must I do in order to have this .ico file display on the top of the page I am printing?

**Edit**
Per the suggestions below I have also tried this syntax

```
Image logoImage = Bitmap.FromHicon(global::Winform1.Properties.Resources.KA0_icon, new Size(48, 48).Handle);
```

however this gives me an error of

> Size' does not contain a definition for 'Handle' and no extension method 'Handle' accepting a first argument of type 'Size' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You might have to share your KA0_icon with us to reproduce the error you are getting.

Comment: @LarsTech - SO will not allow me to upload a file with a .ico type.  Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying an icon in a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782857/displaying-an-icon-in-a-picturebox)

Comment: Icon.ToBitmap() is a bit lame, you'd have to target .NET 4.6 or higher to avoid this exception.  It just isn't the smart way to do this, use the Graphics.DrawIcon() method instead.  Also gives you much better odds of not forgetting to use the *using* statement, the icon should be disposed.

Comment: @HansPassant - can you provide a link to an example or syntax to follow?

Comment: I can't imagine what link you'd need, if you know how to call DrawImage then you know how to call DrawIcon.  All you can do wrong is not trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to debug. Check if your image where you are intended to daw is big enough. An ArgumentOutOfRangeException means, that you are doing stuff that's not in range, so just look how big your image, icon and rectangle is and compare.

And a hint: You should consider to write `(int)(logoImage.Width * 0.75f)` that's what I've learned, because I got sometimes unreliable values.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us, which line is throwing the error!?

Comment: the very first line in my post above.

Comment: You should really visit this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782857/displaying-an-icon-in-a-picturebox) like posted above.

Comment: I have visited that page.  Tried the syntax there and still an error, see my edit.

Comment: Where does the brace go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153060/discussion-between-bagerfahrer-and-smith-stanley).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this similar question:

[Displaying an icon in a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782857/displaying-an-icon-in-a-picturebox)

It mentions the same exception. To do the conversion, you may have success doing something like that:

```
Bitmap.FromHicon(global::Winform1.Properties.Resources.KA0_icon.Handle);
```

Or possibly:

```
Bitmap.FromHicon(new Icon(global::Winform1.Properties.Resources.KA0_icon, new Size(256, 256)).Handle);
```

Comment: I tried both examples you provided and still get the same error :(